# SQL Query : How to Get tweet from following?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want get following tweet, and this my table design.

```
++ follows ++
user_id , account_to_follow
1 , 2
1 , 3
1 , 4

++ tweet ++
user_id, tweet
2, Hallo
3, Hai
4, How aRE YOU
```

How to get all tweet from following where user_id = 1 ?

Comment: Please show the exact expected result.  Also, what did you try? What went wrong? Where are you stuck exactly? It's not clear what you want, or what you've done to try and solve it yourself before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use join to get all tweet from another tables

```
select * from follow f
inner join tweet t on f.account_to_follow = t.user_id
where f.user_id = 1 ;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3otGpf3J14QNTZpAHLdvqg/1